# Expose a directory with Jetty (or, overcoming Same Origin Policy)

Tags: java, jetty, same-origin-policy

I currently have a Java Servlet running via Jetty on port 14436. On the same server, I have some static files in /data/web which are served up via port 80. I therefore encounter a violation of Same Origin Policy when I try and get the static files to talk to the Servlet via javascript.

Is there some easy way I can either:

a) Package the static files into my Java project and have them exposed via Jetty

b) Configure Jetty to expose the /data/web/myproject directory

or some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter

Alternately you can also just wire up either the DefaultServlet to serve those files if you want, or add a ResourceHandler into your handler chain would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving the static content up on port 80 via a web server such as Apache, you can proxy Jetty through the web server. This way you'll also have a more seamless approach without exposing your Jetty port to the world.